# Scan assemblies and automatic binding based on class annotations or inherited type

Tags: c#, ninject-extensions

I need to scan all assemblies for classes with specific attribute (or classes inherited from abstract class **ColorTest**) and automaticly bind them to **ColorTest**.
Then I need to instantiate and enumerate all implementations of **ColorTest**

Assembly 1:

```
public abstract class ColorTest { 
    public abstract string GetColorString();
}
```

Assembly 2:

```
//[ColorImplementation] // attributes are not necessary
public class BlueColor() : ColorTest {...}
```

Assembly 3:

```
//[ColorImplementation] //not necessary
public class RedColor() : ColorTest {...}
```

Assembly 4:

```
class Program{
    public static Main(){

        #region Problem area :)
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();

        kernel.Bind(x => x
            .FromAssembliesMatching("*")
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .InheritedFrom<ColorTest>// or .WithAttribute<ObsoleteAttribute>()
            .BindAllInterfaces() // I'd like to Bind it only to ColorTest
            .Configure(b => b.InSingletonScope()));
        #endregion

        // Enumerate
        kernel
            .GetAll<ColorTest>()
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(t=>Console.WriteLine(t.GetColorString()));
}
```

Example is an abstraction & simplification of more complex problem.

Can Ninject serve me to handle described scenario? If yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was pretty easy!

I had to replace 2 lines:

```
.FromAssembliesMatching("*") -> .FromAssembliesMatching(".") //mistake
```

and

```
.BindAllInterfaces() -> .BindBase() // because I'm implementing 
                                    // abstract class, not interface
```

Attributes were not involved